# What's the equivalent of initializing a tf.Session with tf.ConfigProto in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are two ways I know of for controlling which GPUs a `tf.Session` will take over.  One is the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, the other is initializing a `tf.Session` with an explicit `tf.ConfigProto` and setting `config.gpu_options.visible_device_list`.

When using `nccl`, the environment variable route doesn't work, so `tf.ConfigProto` is the only way.  However, my understanding is that in Tensorflow 2.0 `tf.Session` construction is not explicit.  Is there an equivalent of the `ConfigProto.gpu_options.visible_device_list` route?

Comment: Could you file a bug? We probably need a dedicated "set config options" API now that there's no `enable_eager_execution()` to pass it to.

Comment: ^ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25446

Answer (score 4):

In TF 2.0, the `tf.ConfigProto` options have been moved in various namespace. Mainly [tf.config](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/config) and some in [tf.debugging](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/debugging).

I also suggest to read the [gpu guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/using_gpu).

For your question, I think this option was moved to: `tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices`

Comment: The link to the gpu guide is broken.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [TF 2.0 upgrade script](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/guide/upgrade.md) on your original TensorFlow model, `tf.Session(config=...)` should change to `tf.compat.v1.Session(config=...)` and work as expected. `tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto` can be used to create the config parameter.

[(GitHub issue.)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25446#issuecomment-460500366)

Comment: Will using `tf.compat.v1.Session` work with eager mode?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving - Yes! TF 2.0 is eager by default.